# ebean 8.8.1 lazy load now work with fetch

Tags: fetch, ebean, pagination

here is the code, i want to paginate order with details , but when I add fetch(String s), it does not work

```
class Order

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Detail> details;

class Detail

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    public Order order;
```

no fetch it works

```
  PagedList<Order> pagedList
      = ebeanServer.find(Order.class)
      .where().eq("status", Order.Status.NEW)
      .order().asc("id")
      .setFirstRow(0)
      .setMaxRows(50)
      .findPagedList();
```

add fetch it do not work

```
  PagedList<Order> pagedList
      = ebeanServer.find(Order.class)
      .fetch("details")
      .where().eq("status", Order.Status.NEW)
      .order().asc("id")
      .setFirstRow(0)
      .setMaxRows(50)
      .findPagedList();
```

Comment: What does "fetch it do not work" specifically mean?  Note that Ebean will break that last ORM query into 2 SQL queries.  Ebean must do that to honor the firstRows/maxRows in SQL (which gives the DB the opportunity to optimise the query plan).

Comment: i got it, my table details use composite key, thank you